# *ngFor only showing first element of data set

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using *ngFor to display results from a data set but it is only displaying the first value in the set.

Here is my code

*Data Set*

```
[
  {
    "corporateId": "d0d506f5-a4c4-411a-ba06-a8a36387f824",
    "selectedMAP": [
      {
        "mapId": 4,
        "mapName": "medtest3",
        "active": true,
        "options": [
          {
            "optionId": 4,
            "optionName": "medoptiontest3",
            "optionPrice": 12345,
            "active": true
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "mapId": 5,
        "mapName": "medtest4",
        "active": true,
        "options": [
          {
            "optionId": 5,
            "optionName": "medoptiontest4",
            "optionPrice": 12345,
            "active": true
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

*Get request*

```
  getMedicalAid() {
      this.corporateBenefitsService.getMedicalAidProvider().subscribe((data) => {
            this.existingMedicalProviders = data;
      })
  }
```

*HTML*

```
  <div class="card mb-4" *ngFor="let medicalAid of existingMedicalProviders; let i = index;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="input-container">
            <label for="provider">Provider</label>
            <input id="provider" [(ngModel)]="medicalAid.selectedMAP[i].mapName" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

I currently only see the first `mapName` which is `medtest3`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it out:

```
<div
  *ngIf="existingMedicalProviders"
  class="card mb-4"
  *ngFor="let medicalAid of existingMedicalProviders[0].selectedMAP; let i = index;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="input-container">
          <label for="provider">Provider</label>
          <input id="provider" [(ngModel)]="existingMedicalProviders[0].selectedMAP[i].mapName" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Problem: your `existingMedicalProviders` is array and to get your `selectedMAP` array - you should at first get access to first item of `existingMedicalProviders` array and after that you can iterate through `selectedMAP` ;)

Answer (score 1):

`existingMedicalProviders` is an array with a single element.

You should be iterating over `existingMedicalProviders.selectedMAP`, like below:

**Edit:** You need to use `index` for `[(ngModel)]` [More Info](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

```
<div class="card mb-4" *ngFor="let medicalAid of existingMedicalProviders.selectedMAP; let i = index;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="input-container">
          <label for="provider">Provider</label>
          <input id="provider" [(ngModel)]="existingMedicalProviders.selectedMAP[i].mapName" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also don't see any values on the template with this but console.log has them

Comment: @skydev Edited answer please check

Comment: still gives me a blank even if I just try to bind to a p tag `<p>{{existingMedicalProviders.selectedMAP[i].mapName}}</p>`

Comment: Are you sure all values are set correctly, eg after subscribe, and all variable names and cases are correct?

Comment: the only thing I added is another div with an ngif to wait for the data to be ready `<div *ngIf="existingMedicalProviders">` else I get this error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectedMAP' of undefined`

Comment: Have you tried adding `trackBy` to the statement `*ngFor`?

Comment: I had to do this `existingMedicalProviders[0].selectedMAP[i].mapName`

Comment: @Rushi Patel, have you checked my answer or I was too late ? :D

Comment: Oh, we  missed a minor thing, haha :)

Answer (score 1):

```
  <div class="card mb-4" *ngFor="let medicalAid of existingMedicalProviders?.selectedMAP; let i = index;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="input-container">
            <label for="provider">Provider</label>
            <input id="provider" name="map{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="medicalAid.mapName" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As the others already mentioned your original data set only has a single object inside which does have an array as the property selectedMap.

Is this a correct assumption or did you by mistake present a "wrong" data set?

Additionally, your statement "*I currently only see the first mapName which is medtest3. Any ideas?*" makes sense with your provided code as your are using the following to bind the ngModel:

```
[(ngModel)]="medicalAid.selectedMAP[i].mapName"
```

As said before, you only have a single object in the data set thus the index is 0 (and only 0). Therefore you only see the first value.

To give more insight into your question, please also state where you are calling your method *getMedicalAid()*. Are you doing this from ngOnInit for example? Depending on this it could be that the application behaves differently.

Finally, try to hardcode something in your HTML like:

```
<p>{{existingMedicalProviders.selectedMAP[0].mapName}}</p>
```

*Note*: This is from one of your comments, except that I replaced *[i]* with *[0]*.

To make it even simpler, you could follow an iterative approach and start with

```
<p>{{existingMedicalProviders | json }}</p>
```

which uses [Angulars JSON](https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe) pipe to parse the entire data set object that you assign inside your *getMedicalAid()* method.

Once that works, you can take selectedMAP next.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have only one item in your array.
If you want to iterate the selectedMap then your HTML should be like this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!!existingMedicalProviders">    
    <div class="card mb-4" *ngFor="let item of existingMedicalProviders.selectedMAP">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="input-container">
              <label for="provider">Provider</label>
              <input id="provider" [(ngModel)]="item.mapName" type="text">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: With this I don't see any values on the page. Is it possibly because the values are not there in time?

Comment: I have forgotten to put [0] after existingMedicalProviders as @AlexanderFSP
already replied